# How can I sum values from different documents in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

```
I have photos with an array of likes. I am using mongoose as a db. I want to sum all the numeric values in the likes count of photo collection.
    exports.getAnalytics = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  Campaign.findOne({slug:req.params.slug}, (err, campaign) => {
    PhotoEntries.find({ CampaignId: campaign._id}, ['Photo','Name', 'done' ,'likes_count', ], {sort:{ _id: -1} }, function(err, photos) {
      
      PhotoEntries.countDocuments({CampaignId: campaign._id} , function (err, count) { 
          PhotoEntries.aggregate([
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "$CampaignId",
                Totallikes: { $sum: "$likes_count" }
              }
            }
          ]) 
    if(req.user){
      console.log(photos);
      res.render('admin/analytics', {
        title: 'Analytics',
        campaign: campaign,
        photolist : photos, 
        Count:count ,
        Totallikes: Totallikes  
        });
    }
  // }
  // ])

  });
  });
  });
  }
```

However it is not working. The error is `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators.` How can I achieve this?
Here is my schema code.
var photoSchema = new Schema({
Name: {type: String},
Email:  { type: String },
Photo:  { type: String },
Description:{type:String},
PhoneNumber:{type:String},
CampaignId: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'Campaigns',
},

```
        done: {
          type: Boolean  ,
      },
    
      likes_count: Number ,default: 0,
        likedBy: [
          {
              type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "User"
          }
      ], 
      });
      }
```

I need to add the `likes_count` field to all documents in the collection.

Comment: can you add photo collection schema in your question and expected result.

Comment: What do you want to do? you need to add new field in collection? or just need to count and retrieve through aggregation? your question is not clear.

Comment: Just count and retrieve through aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You missed input `_id`,
Groups input documents by the specified `_id` expression and for each distinct grouping, outputs a document. The `_id` field of each output document contains the unique group by value. For more information refer [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html)

```
PhotoEntries.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      Totallikes: { $sum: "$likes_count" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rq-WlALmOdc)

Comment: What is id: null means , still can't understand?

Comment: it requires input, how it will know to group by this field, you can specify `_id: "$CampaignId"` this will group by that id, -- but now we need to group all documents so `_id: null` this will group all documents. for more information do examples demo from provided $group link in answer.

Comment: I added but unable to send Totallikes variable to front end. It is showing error Totallikes undefined

Comment: there could be no match document in above $match stage, remove that stage and test again.

Comment: I edited above , please check complete route

Comment: there are lots of issues, i don't know why are you doing 3 queries findOne, find and aggregate, and also how you will get result when you don't specify variable before query like `let result = PhotoEntries.aggregate(...)`??

Comment: try to ask proper question refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no one will help you when you change and update your question every time, just focus on your exact problem.

Comment: I am new to this development. that's why i am facing some issues. Any way thanks for helping

Comment: it is ok if you are new everyone will help you but atleast specific on your issue what are you doing and refer reference documents, you will get everything just google it.